# How to start docker daemon in my custom Docker image?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create my custom docker image which I will use in my GitLab build pipeline. (Following this guide as I would like to configure my GitLab runners over AWS Fargate https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/).
One of the prerequisites is to create your own custom docker image that has everything that's needed for the build pipeline to execute.
I would need to add a docker to my docker image.
I am able to install docker, however, I do not understand how to start the docker service as the error I am getting is

***Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?***

each time **docker** command is used.

I tried to add in my startup.sh script used as a docker entrypoint to start docker using rc-service(alpine-based image) or systemctl (amazon linux 2) but without any luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running docker in docker you need to configure docker image with docker-dind service to build docker. But it is limited and requires sudo priviledges, I do recommend to use kaniko, it is very easy to configure, does not require anything more than kaniko executor image.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html

If really need to use DinD (docker in docker), just go to:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Kaniko is simplest and safe way to run docker build

Comment: Thanks but I still can't figure our how to configure it. On their docs it says that I need to use shell or docker executors but I ma using custom one. But if we move aside from gitlab and let's say I just want to configure my own docker image that would start e.g. both sshd and docker inside it, how I can do that in Dockerfile?